# Testing class communicating with DB through ORMLite's DAO

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, ormlite

I'm trying to take a TDD approach in creating Android app. I'm using ORMLite and Mockito/Robolectric for testing. I've run into trouble testing a simple thing:

(method in some class wrapping up DAO calls)

```
public List<ITask> getTasksForNextTwoWeeks() throws SQLException {
    // Code to be written
}
```

Well, the code inside will be just a proper query method call.

What's the best approach to test that code? I've been thinking about this, but can't think of solution without accessing the real database (whether real or test one).

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: +1 for TDD, and the robolectric/mockito combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hrm.  It depends a bit on how you are creating your Dao class.  Under [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/), the Dao class is an interface which means that with a little bit of wiring, you should be able to inject a mocked DAO and just handle the query calls through the mock.

For example, you could have a `setDao` method on your wrapping class sorta like this:

```
public void setDao(Dao<ITask, String> dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}

private Dao<ITask, String> getDao() {
    if (dao != null) {
       // typical ORMLite pattern
       dao = getHelper().getITaskDao();
    }
    return dao;
}
```

Then your `getTasksForNextTwoWeeks()` method would do something like:

```
public List<ITask> getTasksForNextTwoWeeks() throws SQLException {
    QueryBuilder<ITask, String> qb = getDao().getQueryBuilder();
    qb.where().gt(...);
    return qb.query();
}
```

But this requires a good bit of mock-ing to get the `QueryBuilder`.

What we do is extend the ORMLIte `Dao` interface and add metods like `getTasksForNextTwoWeeks()` to the `ITaskDao` class.

```
public interface ITaskDao extends Dao<ITask, String> {
   public List<ITask> getTasksForNextTwoWeeks() throws SQLException;
   ...
}
```

Then you can easily mock out the `ITaskDao` and bypass all of the database operations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now I'm wondering, if it's better to test DAO as a unit or make an integration test with DB up front. Mocking QueryBuilder looks like a overcomplication.

Comment: Agreed.  I recommend for most of your program to mock the Dao out as I mentioned.  But you will still need to test the `ITaskDao` class out as well.

Answer (score 4):

I am not fan of Gray's response, since it makes things little bit too complicated.
I recommend you to simply create in-memory database instead, by passing null as a database name:

```
OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper(context,null, null, DATABASE_VERSION );
```

That way you can test your queries in single test by
a) adding mock elements 
b) testing if your `SqliteOpenHelper`-wrapper returns correct results

Every test like that is completely independent from your actual database and other tests in your suite.